# Excel VBA The webpage is not recognizing the fields are filled in when I submit

Tags: angularjs, vba, excel, internet-explorer

[The exact same issue I have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152411/how-can-i-force-an-angluarjs-form-to-realize-required-fields-have-been-filled-th)

> I've written an Excel VBA macro to paste some data into an AngularJS
>   form -- it opens an Internet Explorer (11) window, navigates to the
>   page containing the form, and crawls the document tree looking for
>   certain elements by their ID, changing their values from blank to
>   non-blank strings from the Excel sheet. However, when I submit the
>   form, the form logic treats all the required fields as if they were
>   still blank, drawing a red box around the supposed offending fields.
>   (I can intervene at this point by clicking into each field, typing a
>   random character at the end of the pasted data and immediately
>   deleting it, and this triggers the logic that the required field is
>   now filled.)

This page from here I linked is the exact same problem I am having with the relevant part highlighted above. The rest I don't anything about. I have tried what was said in the comments about finding the submit and it doesn't work or I am thinking I just need to correct VBA code to submit it correctly.

At best I can tell is when I type it manually, it verifies the field meets the criteria and marks it okay. How do I force this page to check itself after the fields are filled in?

This is what I have tried. Some of these was stuff I found and tried
    `'Call .Document.getelementbyid("firstName").SetAttribute("value", ActiveCell.Value) 'Tried a different way but stayed with my original lines next

    Set firstName = .Document.GetElementById("firstName") ‘works

    firstName.Value = ActiveCell.Value 'works but then for submit, field says empty`
At end of code to submit,
   `.Document.InvokeMember ("vm.onSubmit()")

    Set HTMLForm = .Document.GetElementsByName("vm.onSubmit()")

    HTMLForm.Submit

    .Document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-next")(0).Click ‘works and goes to next page if the fields was working

    .Document.forms(0).submit 'works, just resets the page to previous page`

EDIT: This is what ended up working for me.

```
' Fire the onChange event for the fields on the website 
Dim oEvent 
Set oEvent = .Document.createEvent("HTMLEvents") 
oEvent.initEvent "change", False, True
```

Then wherever you need this next section:

```
    Set firstName = .Document.getElementById("firstName") 
    firstName.Value = ActiveCell.Value ' Column 0, starting column to know where to start the offsets 
    firstName.dispatchEvent oEvent ' Example here since it is used for current field. Each field needs its own change event 

    Set lastName = .Document.getElementById("lastName") 
    lastName.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value ' Column 1 
    lastName.dispatchEvent oEvent
```

The rest of the code just repeats for each field but the dispatchEvent oEvent is what helped me figure this out. It took me trying all kinds of solutions to find the answer at the time but hope this helps.

Comment: Can you share the website URL or the code tried so far?

Comment: Please add this to the question.

Comment: A. Reynolds Have you got the solution for this? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Check my edit to your question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger the `input` event on the fields changed.

```
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 for (var input in inputs) {
   var $input = angular.element(input);
   $input.triggerHandler('input');
 }
```

Comment: I tried this in the VBA code and it isn't recognized. I assume this is something else but how do I trigger the input event fields using this or have VBA trigger them?

Comment: You must execute this in the browser Javascript vm. But I don't know how to do that from vba. Maybe you can trigger the event directly, avoiding Javascript.